# Размер кучи в С++

Tags: c++

Можно ли в С++ ограничивать размеры используемой кучи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересный вопрос, никогда не сталкивался с этим.
А вообще чисто в C++ нету такой функции, для этого используются ОС вызовы.

1. Как сделать под Visual Studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f90ybzkh.aspx

> Установка данного параметра
> компоновщика в среде разработки Visual
> Studio
>
> Откройте диалоговое окно Страницы
> свойств проекта. Дополнительные
> сведения см. в разделе Установка
> свойств проекта Visual C++.
>
> Щелкните папку Компоновщик.
> Выберите страницу свойств Система.
>
> Измените значение свойства Выделить
> память для кучи.

1. Под Линукс

> mallinfo, malloc_stats или команда
> pmap из терминала

Comment: Упс, я даже не знал об этих функциях в лине. Очень интересно.

Comment: Ну есть ещё getrlimit с RLIMIT_DATA

Comment: Я за последний вариант, собственно установка ограничений обеспечивается вызовом setrlimit.

Хорошая статья про организацию стека и кучи [тут](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf).

Comment: Да, конечно, setrlimit